# Matlab histogram vertical axis frequency multiply by constant

Tags: matlab, histogram

The vertical axis of a histogram is the frequency. However, I want them to multiply by a constant. How do I do that with Matlab?

For example:

Tickets are sold at 4 gates: North, South, East or West and I want to plot the amount earned at each gate in a histogram to see which gate earned the most.

The price of each ticket is $10. I want the histogram output to show the amount earned instead of just number of tickets sold.

Answer (score 4):

The `hist` function called with no output assignment will draw the chart for you but if you call it like this

```
[contents, bins] = hist(data)
```

it won't draw the chart and will store the relevant values in the two output variables. Then you can modify the `contents` variable and plot them with `bar` to achieve wht you need

```
bar(bins, 10*contents)
```