# How to multiply a frequency in histogram by scalar

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am using Matlab for this (preferable idea).

I need to multiply a frequency of a histogram by a scalar value (for each bin).
I have tried this approach in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779402/matlab-histogram-vertical-axis-frequency-multiply-by-constant) but it is defined for hist and not histogram function. 
This is my original distribution that needs to be multiplied:
[image: orinial]

This is what I get using the approach given in the similar question:
[image: applied]

Additionally, when I finish this part I will have more histograms that I need to sum up into one histogram. So how would I do that? They might have different ranges.

Comment: What is your data, or your code? You can try `repmat` on the data before the histogram, then you will get multiple amounts of the same data.

Comment: @Adiel Currently I just have a vector of size (150877x1) so I cannot post it here. I plot the histogram for that vector. Now I want to multiply its frequency by scalar. 
Additionally, I will have more of these vectors which I will need to multiply by scalar. In the end, I need to sum them up on one histogram.

Comment: You should try to create a minimum example, describe your approach (show us your code) and the problem you are facing :[ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [clearly explains](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html) how to replicate the behavior of [`hist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) with [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html).

For example:

```
A = rand(100, 1);
h = histogram(A);

figure
h_new = histogram('BinCounts', h.Values*2, 'BinEdges', h.BinEdges);
```

Generates the following histograms:

[image: yay]
[image: yay2]

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the Bincounts like this:

```
X = normrnd(0,1,1000,1); % some data
h = histogram(X,3); % histogram with 3 bins
h.BinCounts = h.Values.*[3 5 1]; % scale each bin by factor 3, 5 and 1 respectively
```